# Not able to use DOMPurify.sanitize in angular application, when imported as an ES6 module

Tags: javascript, angular, server-side-rendering, dompurify

I'm trying to use dompurify in my angular application, where in a service. I'm importing it as

```
import * as DOMPurify from 'dompurify';
```

This works fine when run normally as a CSR application. But if I run it as a SSR, I get

> export 'sanitize' (imported as 'DOMPurify') was not found in
> 'dompurify' (possible exports: default)

I'm using dompurify v3.0.3. On the other hand, If I use

```
const DOMPurify = require('dompurify')
```

It works without an error . But I'm not sure if this is the correct way to use it as angular recommends using ES6 imports.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-dompurify

Comment: @AdamJenkins I actually already tried that, but when i use isomorphic-dompurify I get Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot convert undefined or null to object, when compiling in node 16.19.1

Comment: Where does that error come from? I ran into this same problem on an SSR app and isomorphic dompurify solved it for me

Comment: @AdamJenkins getting error in vendor.js file inside dist/server . which version of isomorphic-dompurify and nodejs were you using ?

Comment: See https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify#running-dompurify-on-the-server